# why my ejs templating is not working in js file

Tags: javascript, ejs

<% -JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %> how to solve this error i am not getting the values of campgrounds as because ejs templating is not working in js file

i am trying to expect a solution to the above problem

Comment: What error do you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching off your auto-formatting in your ide. The proper syntax is:

```
<%- JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>
```